# How to hide group header in grid style View?

Tags: 7, views, theming

How can I hide the headers of the groups in views (Art, Society and Culture) ?

[image]

this is a grid style view of taxonomy grouped by parent term (Drupal 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options :

- hide the relevant elements with CSS.
- override the relevant template to prevent the output of the field.
- depending on the view, tick the checkbox to not display the field in the field properties.

Answer (score 0):

you must go to this location: `\sites\all\modules\views\theme\views-view-grid.tpl` and delete

`<?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>`

or

go to `\sites\all\modules\views\theme\views-view-grouping.tpl` and delete

`<div class="view-grouping-header"><?php print $title; ?></div>`

Comment: You should never hack contrib module files. This breaks the upgrade path. The Drupal theme system should allow you to override these templates for your specific view in your theme.

Comment: I agree with Nick. Override the tpl file, never, *ever* edit core or contrib like this. Read here https://www.drupal.org/node/173880 for more specifics.